# useDelimiter, read up till first delimiter and then change line

Tags: java, delimiter

I'm trying to use a Delimiter to pull out the first numbers in a document with 31 rows looking something like "105878-798##176000##JDOE" and put it in an int array.
The numbers I'm interesed in are "105878798", and the number of numbers is not consistent.

I wrote this but can't figure out how to change the line when i reach the first delimiter (of the line).

```
   import java.util.*;
   import java.io.*;

   public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            int n = 0;
            String rad;

            File fil = new File("accounts.txt");
                int[] accountNr = new int[31];
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(fil).useDelimiter("##");

                    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    rad = sc.nextLine();
                    rad.replaceAll("-","");
                    accountNr[n] = Integer.parseInt(rad);
                    System.out.println(accountNr[n]);
                    n++;
                    System.out.println(rad);
                }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the scanner for this, use the StringTokenizer and set the delimiter to ##, then just keep calling .nextElement() and you will get the next number no matter how long it is.

```
StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(str, "##");

while (st2.hasMoreElements()) {
    log.info(st2.nextElement());
    }
```

(Of course, you can iterate in different ways..)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest for each line use `line.split("[#][#]")[0]` (of course haldle your exceptions).

also, `rad.replaceAll(...)` returns a new String, because String is an imutable object. you should execute `parseInt` on the returned String and not on `rad`.

just use the following instead of the equivalent 2 lines in your code:

```
String newRad = rad.replaceAll("-","");
accountNr[n] = Integer.parseInt(newRad);
```

Comment: I'll look into line.split, but i don't get how to handle my "exceptions"...
Also can you give me some kind of example on the second part? Also, thank you very much!

Comment: Edited it with a little code sample. handle your exceptions means you can't assume `line.split(...)` will return an array of `length > 0`, and therefore you should check it before you're using it's values like I did with `line.split("[#][#]")[0]`

Comment: @gfgqtmakia Why are you using `("[#][#]")` as regex. If you want to limit them to two # only then you can use `"[#]{2}"`

Comment: @user2008449 In the above code `Integer.parseInt(newRad);` This is probable to throw exception if `newRad` is not a string consisted of integers.

Comment: @smit Thank you for the regex advice. Also I've mentioned that exception handling is needed. :-)

Comment: @gfgqtmakia Agree you mentioned about Exception, but where and how. I suggest to update your answer accordingly.

Comment: @smit Generally you should handle any possible exception your code can throw. The best part about programming is finding new exceptions to handle, so why ruin all the fun? :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23390/discussion-between-smit-and-gfgqtmakia)